# In a context-free grammar production rule, how to formally write a production rule $x \rightarrow \text{foo}$ where I don't know what $\text{foo}$ is?

Tags: notation, context-free-grammar

I'm trying to formally describe a production rule $$x \rightarrow \text{foo}$$ in a [context-free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar), but I don't know the value of the right-hand side (only that there is a production rule of the form $x \rightarrow \text{foo}$).

This notation appears within an algorithm, where the algorithm searches for the rule of the form $x \rightarrow \text{foo}$ and changes the $\text{foo}$-value by appending a string.  So the notation $x \rightarrow \alpha$ seems unsuitable since $\alpha$ changes over as the algorithm proceeds.

*Question*: How would one ordinarily formally write a production rule $x \rightarrow \text{foo}$ where I don't know what $\text{foo}$ is, and the value of $\text{foo}$ will change over time?

I'm new to this topic, so I'm interested in what notation is used for $\text{foo}$ ordinarily.  Surely someone has dealt with this notation before and knows the best way to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

[Algorithm 3.40 on p.117 of Elements of Compiler Design
 By Alexander Meduna](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=fZjMBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA117&lpg=PA117&dq=Algorithm+3.40+Chomsky+normal+form&source=bl&ots=e7_KaHLRqz&sig=8Q9ZUpHsg3m_JLzWQh360JtX6d8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7xrjinpfKAhXGsJQKHY4kD8QQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=Algorithm%203.40%20Chomsky%20normal%20form&f=false) has notation for selecting and modifying rules, treating the rule set as a mutable set. You could represent $\text{foo}$ using an uppercase variable like $X$ or $X_{\text{foo}}$ and modify it as needed.